# AppleScript copy file timing out

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

Hello guys I had a simple automator/script to copy one file to another folder, but since the last update of the system (I am using Mojave 10.14.6 with my MacPro), the action will always time out and nothing happens.

```
on run {input}
tell application "Finder"
    copy file (item 1 of input) to folder (item 2 of input)
end tell
end run
```

The input is:

{alias "Watch_Folders:QC:Audio_Video:THEMYSTERYOFHENRIPICK_SOFA_20200910_3185:ElMisterioPick_TLR_F_FR-ES_INT_51_2K_2019-07-15_OV-Reel 1-SOFALAB.mov", "/Volumes/RAID-QC01/SOFA DIGITAL/JOBS/QC/MATEUS/THEMYSTERYOFHENRIPICK_SOFA_20200910_3185"}

**The goal**

For further clarification, what this script does is taking whatever file is selected on the company's server and:

1. Look for the parent folder (it is the vendor id of the job) and extract it
2. Creates a folder on my local HD using the vendor id.
3. Copy the file to the folder.

[image]

So the step one is saving the file's name/location:
[image]

Extracting the folder's name:
[image]

Saving the folder's name (PASTA means folder in portuguese)
[image]

Step two, creates the new folder:
[image]

Saves the new folder as the destiny:
[image]

Recall the file name/location
[image]

Recall the destiny, adding it to the input pool:
[image]

Step three, copy the file:
[image]

Everything goes fine until the last bit. If you think the action should be AppleScript only, I will be happy to delete all the steps, I just don't know how to write it myself.

Comment: Do other _files_ work okay or Is it only this _file_? What type of **Automator** _workflow_ is it and how is the **Run AppleScript** _action_ actually receiving its _input_? Have you tried using **System Events** instead of **Finder** to copy the _file_?

Comment: @user3439894 the workflow takes whatever file is selected. It is a service sending files/forlders to Finder. I could just use Automator Actions but then it won't show the progress bar. It used to work but now it keeps frozen until time out. What I noticed is the input is mixed with HSF and Posix. I am not sure it was like that before. Using System Events will render an error: Can’t make alias "Watch_Folders:QC:Audio_Video:THEMYSTERYOFHENRIPICK_SOFA_20200910_3185:ElMisterioPick_TLR_F_FR-ES_INT_51_2K_2019-07-15_OV-Reel 1-SOFALAB.mov" into type integer.”

Comment: @user3439894 I added "as String", like `copy file (item 1 of input as string) to folder (item 2 of input as string)`, and now the error is: The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “System Events got an error: Files can not be copied.”

Comment: @user3439894 I edited the question to show all the steps.